# Flex - ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller when using added swc file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, parsley

I know already so many questions have been asked here on this error #2025 topic.

But, in my case, it is happening when trying to use a `.swc` file in a flex project.

I am trying to use one of my library project into another flex project by adding using "`Add swc`" file.
I have successfully added it in my new project as a `.swc` file.

But, when I try to use it new project by clicking on the application in browser, it shows me this runtime error. Below is my new project's main file.

**NewSample.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                xmlns:swclib="*"
                layout="absolute">
    <swclib:Main width="100%" height="100%"/>
</mx:Application>
```

**StackTrace:**

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child
>   of the caller.    at
>   flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/getChildIndex()     at
>   mx.managers::SystemManager/getChildIndex()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1772]
>     at
>   mx.managers::SystemManager/mouseDownHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:3615]

I am unable to identify what caused the error ?

---

**EDIT :** This is the main application file of the `.swc` library file.

**Main.mxml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                    xmlns:parsley="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley"
                    minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
                    xmlns:custom="components.*"
                    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" 
                    layout="vertical" 
                    verticalScrollPolicy="off" xmlns:models="models.*" xmlns:views="views.*">
        <views:Header width="100%" height="50"/>
                <mx:HDividedBox id="hdv" width="100%" height="100%">
                    <views:ABC width="15%" height="100%"/>
                    <views:DEF width="65%" height="100%"/>
                    <views:XYZ width="20%" height="100%"/>
                </mx:HDividedBox>

        <parsley:ContextBuilder config="Conf"/>
    </mx:Application>
```

Comment: Please share the code of Main class

Comment: I think you'll need to use Loader to load in an Application.  I have no idea why someone would put an Application Class in a swc...it makes no sense.

Comment: How to use loader ? What should I do now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need `Application`? `Application` should be only the upper one and main class.
Possible solutions:

1. Use another container (for example `Canvas`).
2. Compile your Main.mxml application into swf and then load it with [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class.

I'd prefer to use 1st variant.

Comment: Yes, your preference i.e 1st option worked nicely. +1 from me and accepting your answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are not checking if the (you think child) object is actually a child of the (you think parent) object

Put an `if` there like:

```
if(parentObj.getChildren().indexOf(childObj) >= 0) {
    parentObj.removeChild(childObj);
} else {
    //whatever error logging you do goes here
}
```